# Как сохранить файл на рабочем столе независимо от User

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, desktop

В программе потребовался путь к рабочему столу для создания там файла. Как прописать этот путь чтобы он работал на любом ПК с Windows не завися от Пользователя и т.д. Код пишу на python3.8.1

Answer (score 4):

```py
import os


homeDir = os.path.expanduser('~')
print(homeDir + r'\Desktop')       # Example: C:\Users\Username\Desktop
```

Comment: Рабочий стол может быть перенесён за пределы домашней папки, поэтому этот код работает не всегда.

Comment: @andreymal Вы правы, спасибо за замечание. Я даже не знал об этом. Привёл ещё один способ через `Powershell`, в котором эта проблема, вроде, решена.

Comment: Сохраняет фиг знает куда

Answer (score 3):

Можно получить путь, воспользовавшись `API Powershell`:

```
[Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop")
```

***Пример:***

```py
import sys
import subprocess


output = subprocess.check_output(r'powershell -command "[Environment]::GetFolderPath(\"Desktop\")"')
path = output.decode().strip()
print(path)
```

***stdout:***

```py
C:\Users\Username\Desktop
```

Comment: пишет ошибку `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position 24: invalid start byte`

Answer (score 1):

Это легко сделать, используя winshell

```
import winshell


desktop = winshell.desktop()
print(desktop) # Вывод: C:\Users\пользователь\OneDrive\Рабочий стол
```